# JSSOR - Weird behaviour with arrow button

Tags: jssor

i am writing specifically regarding the weird behaviour arrow button in full-width-slider.source.html

in mac osx mavericks & chrome Version 37.0.2062.94 (also happens to ios chrome) when the left or right arrow button is clicked, then hovering the cursor to the top social media icons and then moving out of the slider container will cause the slider to go back to the previous image.

the problem will get worst if the button is click repeatedly, then hovering the cursor to the top social media icons and then moving out of the slider container will cause the slider to go haywire in an endless loop.

Here is the [video for reference](http://youtu.be/Y51skDbFLDY).

Rgds,
Kong

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I occasionally uploaded a wrong version, you might download in the period. Please download the latest version.

Comment: Thanks JSSOR team, I am testing it now. Will get back if problem persist. Good job for this plugin.