# jssor slides on mouseout with ArrowNavigatorOptions

Tags: javascript, jssor

I am sizing it to the parrent size and everything works great except after you click on one of the arrows, when you leave the slider_container.  It only does this after you click on the arrow and leave the slider_container. Things that I am doing differently form the default things is using a style for the default values in css, and using a div with background img.

code: http://pastebin.com/cSXHPPVY

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I occasionally uploaded a wrong version, you might download in the period. Please download the latest version again.

Comment: See similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636281/jssor-weird-behaviour-with-arrow-button